# MySQL - Querying Large table in MySQL -

Tags: mysql, performance, join

This surely seems like poor design of the college_major table.

```
CREATE TABLE `college_majors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CIPCODE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AWLEVEL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CTOTALT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CTOTALM` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CTOTALW` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAIANT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CASIAT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CBKAAT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHISPT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CNHPIT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CWHITT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C2MORT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUNKNT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CNRALT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=270167 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I can reduce this table to three columns - id, CIPCODE and UNITID.  But the problem is even simple queries like *select * FROM college_majors* is taking too long to execute and sometime not even executing.

I increased the query execution to 6000.00 sec, but still the query won't run.

Any suggestion on how to improve the design, create a new table and insert the data from this table (college_majors).

Thanks,
A

Comment: For one thing, there's no point of using a `LEFT JOIN` with your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: is there a reason for doing left join college_majors_mapping? That slows the query down.

Comment: Seems like the table design for college_majors is not correct. I can simplify it to a three column table with id, CIPCODE and UNITID. and then insert the data to a new table. But even when I am running a query on college_majors, even simple queries like 

select * FROM a4c_college_majors;

it is taking too much time around 600-800 secs. Any suggestions?

Comment: You do not appear to have any useful indexes on the table for joins. These are VERY important for anything more than a very basic query to execute acceptably.

Comment: Yes. Step 1 has to be to read up on normalization. Step 2 will be the correct application of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If field 'codevalue' in college_majors_mapping is unique you can indexed it and increase join performance.

Comment: The problem is with the main table design as even simple select query fails.

Comment: MyISAM isn't reliable engine, so do you check this table on the errors? Like http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-check.html